# Ломается роутинг при сокращении кода

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

Пишу приложение на react/router. В родительском компоненте App есть три дочерних компонента: Menu, Burger, Order. В каждом из них есть ссылка на следующий: из Menu в Burger, из Burger в Order, из Order в Menu.

Фрагмент кода из **App.js**:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
    <Route path='/hamburger' component={Burger}/>
    <Route path='/cheeseburger' component={Burger}/>
    <Route path='/chickenburger' component={Burger}/>
    <Route path='/fishburger' component={Burger}/>
    <Route path='/order' component={Order}/>
</Switch>
```

Фрагмент кода из **Menu.js**:

```
<ul>
    <li><Link to='/hamburger' component={Burger}>Гамбургер</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/cheeseburger' component={Burger}>Чизбургер</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/chickenburger' component={Burger}>Чикенбургер</Link></li>
    <li><Link to='/fishburger' component={Burger}>Фишургер</Link></li>
</ul>
```

Фрагмент кода из **Burger.js**:

```
<Link to="/order" container={Order}>Продолжить</Link>
```

Фрагмент кода из **Order.js**:

```
<Link to="/" container={Menu}>Купить</Link>
```

Очевидно, что код в файле App.js можно сократить. Вместо 4 Route со ссылками на компонент Burge можно написать всего одну строку. Я пробовал писать следующим образом:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
    <Route path='/:id' component={Burger}/>
    <Route path='/order' component={Order}/>
</Switch>
```

В результате с компонентом Burger всё нормально. Внутри него я смог настроить отображение и hamburger, и cheeseburger, и chickenburger, и fishburger. **НО** при переходе из Burger в Order, Order не отображается.

Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы проста все  с похожим роутем не вместить в массив?

Рабочий [**codesandbo**x](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-mccarthy-yyxg7)

Вот так:

```
function App() {
  const path = ["/hamburger", "/cheeseburger", "/chickenburger", "/fishburger"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Menu} />
        <Route path={path} component={Burger} />
        <Route path="/order" component={Order} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

А  **Menu.js** можно сократить вот так

```
const path = {
    hamburger: "Гамбургер",
    cheeseburger: "Чизбургер",
    chickenburger: "Чикенбургер",
    fishburger: "Фишургер"
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      {Object.keys(path).map(el => (
        <li key={el}>
          <Link to={`/${el}`} component={Burger}>
            {path[el]}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
```

Comment: Да! То, что я хотел
ПС.В версии компонента Menu для себя я применял map. В версии для SO упростил